# Expo firebase auth provider is undefined

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, expo

I'm using firebase facebook for my app. I just want user's public profile so that I can create user in my database. I do not want firebase full authentication just the profile detail but I am getting the following error.[image]

Here is some code

```
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: FIREBASE_KEY,
  authDomain: FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
  databaseURL: FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL,
  projectId: FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET
}
export const Firebase = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

async loginWithFacebook(navigate){
  const { type, token} = await Expo.Facebook.logInWithReadPermissionsAsync(FACEBOOK_APP_ID, {
    permissions: ['public_profile'],
  });
  if (type == 'success') {

    const provider = new Firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider();
    const credential = provider.credential(token);
    Firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(credential)
    .then((user) => {})
    .catch((error) => {
  });
  }

}
```

I'm very new in react native please let me know what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: How did you solve this error @Asnad? I tried a solution of @bojeil but didn't work.

Comment: @ganeshdeshmukh I removed firebase and used https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/facebook but the answer from bojeil is also correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code to the following:

```
const credential = Firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.credential(token);
Firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(credential)
```

`credential` is a static method on `firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider`.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I tried this and got error "[Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'Firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.credential')]"